# Como transforma um carácter em um símbolo matemático?

Tags: java, operadores

Eu tenho uma dúvida, eu consigo converter uma variável do tipo char ou String em um operador matemático? É possível? A linguagem que uso é Java.

Por exemplo:

```
int n1 = 1, n2 = 1;

char simb = '+';

int resultado = 1 simb 1. 

resutado = 2;
```

Comment: Não é muito o que eu quero não

Comment: Não foge muito das respostas da duplicata, a não ser que você faça uma solução "porca" que seria analisar cada caractere e detectar os simbolos com `switch...case`.

Comment: Então explica melhor a pergunta, porque você disse "converter uma variável do tipo char ou String em um operador matemático" e me parece exatamente isso, se é outra coisa seria melhor explicar exatamente, ou talvez você não tenha entendido as respostas. Veja que são 3 respostas diferentes, olhe as 3 com atenção.

Comment: Ok, verei novamente, valeu!

Comment: Pessoal me desculpem mas não entendi como faz, sou novo ainda em programação, poderia me dar um exemplo, sem deixar programação "porca"?

Comment: @ChristianGomesdaSilva Explique melhor o que você quer fazer. Por que você quer usar uma string como um operador matemático?

Comment: Então @VictorStafusa eu estou desenvolvendo um app que contém 3 níveis de dificuldade e 3 atividades para cada nível, e este app contempla as 4 operações matemáticas básicas. Ai para não ter que fazer 3 activitys para cada operação e outros 3 layouts, gostaria de usar as mesma três activitys que eu já fiz, e com o carácter eu conseguiria alterar os símbolos das operações, por isso eu queria saber como fazer uma string ou char que tem o símbolo da operação, para fazer as trocas nas operações.

Comment: Ou seja, você tinha um problema X, mas fez uma pergunta sobre um problema Y completamente diferente. Veja mais sobre isso [**aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). A solução adequada passa muito longe disso que você perguntou. Sugiro postar uma pergunta nova refeita do zero.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pelo conselho, irei refazer uma nova pergunta do zero e postar, e mais uma vez valeu!